# how i get data from crawler to my site?

Tags: php, web-services, web-crawler

what is the best way to get data from external crawler to my DATA BASE, to my site
i work in LAMP environment, 
is web services is good idea ? the crawler run every 15 minutes.

Comment: Can you tell us more about this crawler?

Comment: the crawler run on some boards sites and give the data and the link to the site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the crawler, but theoretically, yes, web services are the best option. You just have to parse the XML replies into your DB.